# How to fix "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeCamera.default.constants')" error in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-camera

I'm trying to use "React-native-camera" library in my project. I've literally done this over 50 times and everything went fine each time both on my mac and Linux System.

But now out of a sudden it wont work on my Linux System anymore and keeps generating this error (works on mac though!).

[image]

I've checked all the configuring steps [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera)
I've tried adding missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general' to app build.gradle
I've tried adding maven {url "https://jitpack.io"} and maven {url "https://maven.google.com"} to project build.gradle
I've tried removing madules.xml from .ideas directory and restarting android studio both with and without cache clearing.

still nothing
This was my sample code to get the camera module going:

```
class CameraApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      path: null,
      uri: '',
      imageName: ''
    };
  }

  takePicture() {
    this.camera.capture()
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);  
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
}

  renderCamera() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Camera
          ref={(cam) => {
            this.camera = cam;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}
          captureTarget={Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.disk}
        >
          <TouchableHighlight
            style={styles.capture}
            onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}
            underlayColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)"
          >
            <View />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </Camera>
      </View>
    );
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.renderCamera()}
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same problem...

Comment: nope not yet. i guess I'm just gonna use the old good RNCamera instead.

Comment: Any solution for this

Comment: @seijn 
import {RNCamera} from 'react-native-camera';
then use RNCamera ( 
     <RNCamera
          ref={ref => {
            this.camera = ref;
          }}
          ...

Answer (score 5):

There are three issues here:

**First**, the import should be like:

```
import {RNCamera as Camera}  from 'react-native-camera';
```

**Second**, the `constants` must have the first letter capitalized: `Constants`

**Third**, both `Aspect.fill` and `CaptureTarget.disk` are no longer part of the `Constants`. So you should delete the following two lines:

```
  aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}
  captureTarget={Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.disk}
```

And you may check for the updated alternatives of those constants at there official documentation at https://react-native-community.github.io/react-native-camera/docs

Answer (score 4):

I found this link, maybe helpful to you (it work for me):
[Issue #1288 react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/1288#issuecomment-368652124)

You should import like this:

`import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';`

Not like this

`import Camera from 'react-native-camera';`

Comment: I change like you suggested, got ReferenceError : Can't find variable : Camera

Comment: @Rickard how did you fix this issue?

Comment: Just change every mention of Camera and start using RNCamera, it is the same Object.